# How to force compiler to promote variable to float when doing maths

Tags: c, math

I got question about math in C, quick example below:

```
uint32_t desired_val;
uint16_t target_us=1500
uint32_t period_us=20000;
uint32_t tempmod=37500;


desired_val = (((target_us)/period_us) * tempmod);
```

At the moment (target_us/period_us) results in 0 which gives desired_value also 0. I don't want to make these variables float unless i really have to. I dont need anything after comma as it will be saved into 32bit register.

Is it possible to get correct results from this equation without declaring target_us or period_us as float? I want to make fixed point calculations when it's possible and floating point when it's needed.

Working on cortex-M4 if that helps.

Comment: By doing the multiplication *first*, if necessary with a larger data type. `target_us * tempmod / period_us`

Comment: If floating point is the issue, consider fixed point math.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think that guarantees a particular order of operation. Parentheses just override operator precedence.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't need anything after comma as it will be saved into 32bit register"?  I see no commas, only some semicolons.  What's wrong with adding a `(float)` cast to `target_us` in the expression?  (Though I'd prefer to use `double` — `float` has very limited precision.)

Comment: @jean-François: since C requires left-associative evaluation of multiplicative operators, your expression and weather's are guaranteed to produce identical results.

Comment: FYI, all of the math you are doing barely into 32-bit registers at the moment.  You may either have to normalize your data or consider using bigger registers if you need perfect results (or multiple 32-bit registers and let the compiler help).  Even using floating point is throwing away precision.  The question would really be, what do you mean by "I don't need anything after comma..."  That means you only need up to 3 or 4 decimals precision?

Comment: @barmar: associativity is part of operator precedence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think "comma" means "decimal point" -- he's not concerned with any fraction in the result.

Comment: I'm still worried that his numbers are on the edge of ok at 32-bit.  If his data domain  gets any larger, it will overflow with the multiply done first.  I'd be thinking 64-bit to be safe, or float if not possible.

Comment: Which is where I began.

Comment: Double operations eats up a lot of processor cycles, floating are way better with in-build FPU but still precision is not that important because everything at the end will be rounded to fixed point.

Comment: Doesn't your FPU handle `double`? The `float` isn't far from being obsolete.

Comment: `float` is slower. Only useful when you want to transmit/read/write huge arrays of data and cannot afford the bandwith (because float requires twice as less memory)

Comment: Does your M4 board have FP hardware?  It's optional for that chip...

Comment: Yes my chip got FPU build-in. It doesn't support double operations  so i'm trying to avoid double as much as i can, float is reasonable and i will stick with float casting for now.

Comment: @Barmar the operators `*` and `/` have equal precedence, but left-to right associativity. So `3 / 4 * 5` will give `0`, but `3 * 5 / 4` will give `3`.

Comment: Absolutely true, @WeatherVane, but as a matter of style, I would still enclose the multiplication operation in parentheses.  Two extra characters to take the question completely off the table.

Answer (score 3):

Do the multiplication first.

You should split it into two statements with a temporary variable, to ensure the desired order of operations (parentheses ensure proper grouping, but not order).

```
uint64_t tempprod = (uint64_t)target_us * tempmod;
desired_val = tempprod / period_us;
```

I've also used `uint64_t` for the temporary, in case the product overflows. There's still a problem if the desired value doesn't fit into 32 bits; hopefully the data precludes that.

Comment: make `tempprod` a `uint64_t`. Given the datatypes of target & tempmod, this could overflow otherwise. and cast one of the operands to 64 bits too. I'd do `uint64_t tempprod = (uint64_t)target_us * tempmod`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that and added a caveat if the final result doesn't fit.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "parentheses ensure proper grouping, but not order"? I always thought that when I write `(a*b)/c`, `a*b` would be computed first. Or is optimizer free to rearrange? Some other thing?

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes, the optimizer is allowed to rearrange it, as long as it's mathematically equivalent.

Comment: Even when division would be done at 32 bits and multiplication at 64 bits?

Comment: I think it's allowed to do everything in 64 bits, then reduce it at the end.

Comment: Your solution took more than 250 cycles to complete, when solution with float casting as someone suggested in comments took less than 50. Seems like uint64_t operations aren't that fast?

Comment: @akimata Probably depends on whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit CPU.

Comment: You said you didn't want to cast to floating point, so I don't see the point of comparing to that.

Comment: It's 32bit CPU so maybe that's why, need to investigate it further. I didn't want to cast it to float to avoid floating point maths, because they tend to be slow but seems like uint64_t are even slower.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do some casting in any case, but there's two different methods. First, stick with integers and do the multiplication first:

```
desired_val = ((uint64_t)target_us * tempmod) / period_us;
```

or do the calculations in floating point:

```
desired_val = (uint32_t)(((double)target_us / period_us) * tempmod);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the computation with `double` quite easily:

```
desired_val = (double)target_us  * tempmod / period_us;
```

`float` would be a mistake, since it has far too little precision to be reliable.

You might want to round that off to the nearest integer rather than letting it be truncated:

```
#include <math.h>
desired_val = round((double)target_us  * tempmod / period_us);
```

See [man round](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/round.3.html)

You could, of course, do the computation using a wider integer type (for example, replacing the `double` with `int64_t` or `long long`). That will make rounding slightly trickier.

Comment: His CPU does not have double supported FPU hardware.  This becomes software emulation.